# Why can't I disable the sparse-checkout of Git?

Tags: git, git-sparse-checkout

I cloned a repository and found that it has the "SPARSE" after "master". I am not so familiar with git, so I search it in the official document, which says that I can disable it by "git sparse-checkout disable". However, I tried it and it seems that nothing changed:

[image: See the image here]

Can anyone tell me how can I remove the "SPARSE"?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Just include the text itself, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: Running `git sparse-checkout disable` *should* have worked. However, the new sparse checkout mode work is rather experimental and various releases of Git may have bugs here. What version of Git are you using? (run `git --version`, cut and paste the command and its result.)